# Core Data: Ubiquity: error loading comparison metadata for transaction logs

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

It's my first question here in StackOverflow.

Here's a problem I'm having:

I'm trying to access Core Data data from iCloud. It has been working flawlessly over the past month. But suddenly, without adding any code to the project, this error comes up when testing the code in a debugger:

```
 -[_PFUbiquityRecordsImporter createSortedOperationsArrayForLogLocationsInContext:isFirstImport:](252): CoreData: Ubiquity: Error loading comparison metadata for transaction log: (null)
  Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)"
```

That one's been appearing for all of the records from one device. Strangely, it does not appear for records taken over the cloud from another device. As a result, I can only access the records from the other device, not the one this error is on. Any ideas?

Comment: glad you posted. i have the same problem..